# Taylor flat plate theory with local cavitation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, explosions, shock-waves

**Background**

I'm studying the so-called Taylor flat plate theory. The problem considers an infinite plate which separates a region of water from a region of air. There is an incident shockwave from the water side, which becomes reflected off the plate. We consider only normal reflection, not oblique reflection. The pressure on the waterside of the plate causes the plate to move. We assume that the plate can not bend, so that only rigid body motion is possible.

The incident shockwave is of the form $p_1 = p_0 e^{-nt}$, where $p_0$ is the peak pressure, and $n$ is a decay constant. The plate has mass per unit area $m$. The equation of motion takes the form
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&m \ddot{x} + \rho c \dot{x} = 2 p_0 e^{-n t},\\
&x(t=0) = \dot{x}(t=0) = 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Here $\rho$ and $c$ are the waters density and speed of sound.

**Solution**

The displacement $(x)$, velocity $(\dot{x})$, and pressure $(p)$ on the plate are given by \begin{equation}
x(t) = \frac{2 p_0}{mn^2\left(\epsilon -1\right)\epsilon} \left(\epsilon - 1 + e^{-n\epsilon t} - \epsilon e^{-nt} \right),
\label{eq:Taylor_displacement}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t) = \frac{2 p_0}{mn \left(\epsilon - 1\right)} \left( e^{-nt} - e^{-n\epsilon t} \right),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{p}{p_0} = \frac{2}{\epsilon - 1} \left(\epsilon e^{-n \epsilon t} - e^{-nt} \right)
\end{equation}
respectively. Here we have introduced the dimensionless parameter
\begin{equation}
\epsilon = \frac{\rho c }{nm}.
\end{equation}

The interesting aspect of the above solution is that at the special time
\begin{equation}
t^* = \frac{\ln \epsilon}{n(\epsilon -1)}.
\end{equation}
the pressure changes from being positive to being negative. There are then three cases which emerge:

1. The water sticks to the plate throughout the motion, and does not cavitate.
2. The water looses contact with the plate, but does not cavitate.
3. The water looses contact with the plate, but cavitates.

Case 1) is fine, as all of the equations above apply.

Case 2) (and 3) ?) can be described by saying that the pressure on the plate is zero for $t>t^*$. The problem is studied in the review article 'A review of underwater explosion phenomena'', E. N. Fox, Cambridge University, page 37. In addition, to the pressure cut-off the author introduces a spring (with spring contant $k$) which decelerates the plate. [The article is openly available here](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/tr/AD0006841), but I attempt to include enough detail in the question in case the link someday expires.

**Question**

To analyze case 2 and 3, the author introduces the two functions $\Omega'$ which is the energy transferred to the plate, and $\Omega_i$ which is the energy in the pressure pulse, indicent on the area of the plate. For case 2) the author states that $\Omega' = 1/2 mv_0^2$ and $\Omega_i = p_0^2 / 2 \rho c n$, and plots the ratio $\Omega'/\Omega_i$ in the fugure below (case 2).

My confusion comes from how $\Omega'$ and $\Omega_i$ should look in case 3 where we have cavitation. The author states that the total energy to be absorbed by the resistance $kx$ is the total energy $\Omega_i$ of the original incident pulse less the energy $\Omega_r$ of the positive potion of the reflected pulse which travels away to large distances from the plate. Then, to my frustration, the figure below is plotted, without giving explicit expressions for the ratio $\Omega'/\Omega_i$ for case 3. The figure shows that much more energy is transferred to the structure when the water cavitates.

My question is if someone can paint a clear picture of why there is more energy transferred to the plate if the water cavitates, compared to the case without cavitation. An explicit expression for $\Omega'/\Omega_i$ in case 3) is also highly appreciated, but I realize this may be difficult.

[image: Image taken from p.37 in ''A review of underwater explosion phenomena'', E. N. Fox, Cambridge University]

Edit: I have included a sketch that the author uses to describe the cavitation mechanism
[image: sketch that the author uses to describe the cavitation mechanism]

Comment: Anything I can do to make the question more accessible/relevant?